# GL_TEXTURE8 not working with GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY

Tags: opengl

I have a weird issue. Whenever I bind GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY to GL_TEXTURE8, I get black textures. I am using an Intel HD3000 GPU that has 16 texture units. Any other types of texture work fine except GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY.

Is it possible, that this is a driver or hardware issue? Is there a way to check if something failed during the process of uploading textures?

```
  glGenTextures(1, &id);
  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE8);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, id);
  glIsTexture(id); // Returns true (1)
```

Comment: Did you check that your texture is Ok for other texture units? Also, check your sampler type in GLSL shader.

Comment: This question cannot be answered without seeing the code that *uses* the texture.

Comment: Basically if I change to any other than GL_TEXTURE8 and set the appropriate glUniform1i, everything works. I am now trying to find out if somewhere else GL_TEXTURE8 is being "played with". I can't post the code. It would be 10.000 lines of code. The texture loading code is basically OpenGL 101.